# Sort/Group by the number of documents with equal fields in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, sorting, document

What I want to achieve is grouping these documents,

```
{voteid: A, userid: x}, {voteid: C, userid: x},
{voteid: A, userid: y}, {voteid: A, userid: z},
{voteid: C, userid: z}, {voteid: D, userid: z}
```

in objects with number of votes (users are irreleveant here) and also sorting them based on **voteid**:

```
{voteid: A, votes: 3},
{voteid: C, votes: 2},
{voteid: D, votes: 1}
```

How should I approach that?

I'm working with MongoDB 3.0 Node.js driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so this will help you do your query (count) and sort them for `voteid`,

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate([{
     $group: {
        _id: '$voteid',
        votes: {$sum: 1}
     }
   },
   {
     $sort: {
       _id: 1
     }
   },
   {
     $project: {
      _id: 0,
      voteid: '$_id',
      votes: 1
     }
   }
])
```

What we are doing here is first apply `$group` operator on the records and find all the occurences of the `voteid` by assigining it to `_id` as accumulator object and subsequently storing count values -- `{$sum: 1}` in `votes`.

Then, we **sort** based on `_id` we just created with `votesid` and then project the result in the form we needed -- eliminating `_id` and remapping the previous group `_id` to `voteid` and allowing votes in our result.

**Hope this helps.**